# Glitchy black patches using imageWithData in a UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiscrollview, uiimage, nsdata

I have been having a tough time with memory consumption in a hefty app. I've got rid of almost all memory leaks.  One section has a zoomable `UIScrollView` of a map that's pretty large: 2437x1536. It chooses between pngs in an array. Before I was using `+imageNamed:`, but I heard that this can make apps sometimes run poorly because it may keep the image in cache, which can consume more memory even if you're out of the view that was using it. Now I'm using `+imageWithData:`. The app hasn't crashed yet, but upon the 4th or 5th time of launching the map section, only some of the image appears, and there's flickering black areas. It didn't happen before with imageNamed. Sometimes it entirely disappears except for just a rectangular upper corner, and I go back to another view, and an image is flashing there too.

Here's what I have to display the map image. It's in a view's `-initWithFrame:` method:

```
mapList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[mapList addObject:@"Pacific_Map"];
[mapList addObject:@"Atlantic_Map"];

NSString *mapFileLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[map_List objectAtIndex:mapNum] ofType:@"png"];

NSData *mapIMGData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:mapFileLocation];
mapImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithData:mapIMGData]];
```

Anything obvious that would be causing this effect?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I was allocating an image for the external screen twice.  This still eventually makes it crash.  I thought I'd be not caching the image with this technique.